# Python script with pyodbc code not running using EXE made from py2exe

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe, pyodbc

I made a small Python Tkinter application that does some stuff with .mdb files using the pyodbc extension. I tried making an EXE using py2exe, but get the following error when I try to run the EXE.

```
Traceback (most recent call list):
File "My_Python_Script.py", line 14, in <module>
File "pyodbc.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "pyodbc.pyc", line 10, in __load
RuntimeError: Unable to import decimal
```

Where line 14 in my script is where I am importing pyodbc. I tried making an EXE of another python script that does not use pyodbc and it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to explicitly tell py2exe to include some additional modules:

```
setup(
        ...
        options={
                "py2exe": {
                        "includes": ["decimal"]
                }
        }
)
```